# Python как хитро переместить файл

Tags: python, файлы, permissions, copy

Есть серверное решение на Ubuntu20, которое читает входную папку примерно раз в секунду. Если в нее через МС скопировать файл из другой папки, то все отрабатывается корректно. Если я копирую или переношу в нее файл в скрипте, то иногда не происходит корректной обработки. Логов в модуле загрузки нет, ошибки не возникают... до разработчика не достучаться. Предполагал что пока копируется файл (50-200 Кб) сервак начинает считывать файл и не дожидаясь полной загрузки приступает к обработке, в результате снова сбой. Пробовал следующие варианты переноса: shutil.move/Path().rename()/subprocess.Popen/os.replace/os.rename - раз через раз срабатывает. Может кто знает причину или иные варианты копирования ?

Comment: Если сервер будет игнорировать скрытый файл, то можно использовать это. Т.е. делать файл скрытым, копировать, а по окончании переноса делать вновь обычным

Comment: Также можно забрать у программы на сервере разрешение на чтение файла, пока перенос не будет выполнен (что, возможно, приведет к ошибкам в серверной программе после того, как ОС запретит ей прочитать файл). И еще, https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-locking , правда это решение не самое надежное)

Comment: Вы проверяли, что перенос выполняется в пределах одной файловой системы? Если файловые системы разные, то всё равно получится копирование

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим. Пока я отрабатываю на следующем механизме: Тестовый файл копируется во временную папку, от туда и я пытался перекинуть файл во входную. 1) Если я делаю файл во временной папке скрытым, то не могу изменить permission, получаю ошибку. 2) Сильно начинающий в Python, не уверен в совете 2. Сотрудничество с учетом блокировки у нас не поддерживается. 3) Да, в соседней папке лежат тестовые файлы, ФС одна и та же. Когда копирую тот же самый файл средствами ОС и файловым менеджером, то все работает. У меня не работает даже перенос. Может быть что-то нужно закрывать ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `shutil.copy2()` дожидается полного выполнения копирования и только потом продолжает работу скрипта.
Пример выполнения:

```
import shutil

src_file = '/путь_к_исходному_файлу'
dst_file = '/путь_к_целевой_папке/файл'

shutil.copy2(src_file, dst_file)
```

Comment: Только вот это никак не приостановит работу «серверного решения», которое начнёт сразу же читать недокопированный файл

Comment: пробовал и такой вариант. Сейчас пробую управлять читающим приложением - останавливать, копировать файл и снова запускать. Создал новый вопрос, не очень и там у меня выходит.